# Why are writes on a NVME not much faster than SATA SSD in Linux?

Tags: linux, ssd, performance, nvme

I am using a 970 EVO 1TB NVME SSD and a MX300 SATA SSD in my system.

After running some benchmarks I realized that the NVME SSD is not as fast as I hoped it would be.

According to the gnome disk benchmark I get and avg. write speed of 620 MB/s on my NVME and 499 MB/s on my SATA SSD. I get the same results when copying files manually.

Does NVME SSDs have to be configured specially in Linux?

[image]

[image]

Edit:

I installed Windows and copied a 12 GB file on both systems. Under Windows I have about twice the performance as under Linux.

[image]
[image]

Comment: That's still a 25% speed increase...

Comment: According to the specs I should get 2500MB/s SLC-Cached (1200MB/s TLC).

Comment: UserBenchmark results for comparison: https://ssd.userbenchmark.com/SpeedTest/693540/Samsung-SSD-970-EVO-Plus-1TB

Comment: @gronostaj I actually only have the none pro variant https://ssd.userbenchmark.com/SpeedTest/494791/Samsung-SSD-970-EVO-1TB but there isn't a big difference.

Comment: Is Linux running in a VM? Test with a bigger sample size. Maybe the tool measures wrong with such small test files. Did you trim before starting the benchmark?

Comment: @mgutt I am not running in a VM, trim is enabled by default. With a sample size of 1GB I get 710 MB/s. Maybe the benchmark is not a good indicator, but how can the file copy be so much slower?

Comment: Then you need to update your question and add more details how the VMs of Linux and Windows are created (which VM software is used and which settings).

Comment: @mgutt NOT in a VM

Comment: Sorry, overlooked ^^